How to determine the distance of a given point to an ellipse? Does it lie inside a $2h$ width boundary around it? Best in implicit form
As an explicit vectorial equation we can write an ellipse like this (based on this):
$$P(t)=C_\circ+a\cdot \vec{u} \cdot \cos t+b \cdot \vec{v} \cdot \sin t$$
With $C_\circ$ being the center
$$C_\circ = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_\circ \\ y_\circ \end{array}\right) $$
And $a$ and $b$ the length of the major and minor axis.
And $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ their orthogonal unit direction vectors. 
If an ellipse is rotated by $\theta$ in clockwise direction this would be :
$$\vec{u} =  \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos  \theta \\ -\sin \theta \end{array}\right) $$
$$\vec{v} =  \left(\begin{array}{c} \sin \theta \\ \cos \theta \end{array}\right) $$
To determine the distance from this ellipse we first compute the tangent by making a derivation of $P(t)$
$$P(t)' =  -a\cdot \vec{u} \cdot \sin t+b \cdot \vec{v} \cdot \cos t$$
Now we rotate it $90°$ in clockwise direction. $\vec{v}$ is $90°$  counterclockwise of $\vec{u}$. So $90°$ clockwise rotation makes $\vec{v}$ to $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{u}$ to $-\vec{v}$
$$N(t) = a\cdot \vec{v} \cdot \sin t+b \cdot \vec{u} \cdot \cos t $$
The magnitude of this vector is
$$||N(t)|| = \sqrt{a^2\cdot  \sin^2 t+b^2 \cdot  \cos^2 t }$$
($\vec{u}^2 = 1 $ and $\vec{v}^2 = 1 $ due to being unit vector)
With this we can generate a inner and outer boundary with distance of $h$ to the ellipse
 Outer boundary
$$O(t) = P(t) + h \frac{N(t)}{||N(t)||} $$
And Inner boundary
$$I(t) = P(t) - h \frac{N(t)}{||N(t)||} $$
Example picture:


Now my question is given a point $\vec{p} =  \left(\begin{array}{c} x_p \\ y_p \end{array}\right) $ can we determine if this point is inside this inner and outer boundary and compute the distance to the ellipse?

Trials:
We could use $O(t)$ and $I(t)$ and replace $h$ by a distance variable $d$ with the result of our point in question $\vec{p}$
$$\vec{p} = P(t) + d \frac{N(t)}{||N(t)||} $$
We transform it to be able to compute the distance from $\vec{p}$ to every ellipse point on angle $t$
$$d = \frac{\vec{p} - P(t)\cdot ||N(t)||}{N(t)} $$
To find the minimal $t$ we can do some derivation of $d$ by $t$
$$d' = -\frac{\vec{p} \cdot N'(t) + ( P'(t)\cdot ||N(t)|| + P(t)\cdot ||N(t)||' ) N(t) - P(t)\cdot ||N(t)|| \cdot N'(t) }{N(t)^2} $$
and set it zero to find best $t$
$$ 0 = -\frac{\vec{p} \cdot N'(t) + ( P'(t)\cdot ||N(t)|| + P(t)\cdot ||N(t)||' ) N(t) - P(t)\cdot ||N(t)|| \cdot N'(t) }{N(t)^2} $$
$P'(t)$ we already computed on top. Here the missing $N'(t)$ and $||N(t)||'$
$$N'(t) = a\cdot \vec{v} \cdot \cos t - b \cdot \vec{u} \cdot \sin t $$
$$||N(t)||' = \frac{(a^2-b^2) \sin t \cos t}{\sqrt{a^2\cdot  \sin^2 t+b^2 \cdot  \cos^2 t }}$$
Inserting all values and let it simplify with a software I got a very unpleasing looking equation 
(Edit: removed some long equations which turned out to be wrong

One problem might be the equation of $d$. I divide by a vector there.
/EndEdit )

Does anyone know how to continue or have a better idea?
The final goal is to compute this for many points as possible $\vec{p}$ so an implicit formula like this ellipse equation
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$
would be nice.

If you would like to try for yourself, here are the equations used in text from:
P = C + a *u*cos(t) + b * v * sin(t);
Pd = -a *u*sin(t) + b * v * cos(t);
N = a *v*sin(t) + b * u * cos(t);
Nd = a *v*cos(t) - b * u * sin(t);
Nn = sqrt(a^2 *sin(t)^2 + b^2 * cos(t)^2 );
Nnd = (a^2-b^2)*sin(t)*cos(t)/sqrt(a^2 *sin(t)^2 + b^2 * cos(t)^2 );

d = (p - P * Nn)/N;
dd = (p*Nd + (Pd*Nn+P*Nnd)*N-P*Nn*Nd )/N^2;


The first thing to do is to make a change of variables so that the ellipse is now expressed in its canonical coordinates as
$$
\frac{X^2}{A^2}+\frac{Y^2}{B^2}=1
$$
The ellipse is centered and aligned with axes and
we suppose $A\geq B \geq 0$.
The point to be projected is expressed in this new frame as $(U,V)$ and without loss of generality we can suppose $U>0,V>0$.
We are now looking for the point $(X,Y)$ on the ellipse such that for some real $t$
\begin{eqnarray*}
U-X = t\frac{X}{A^2} &,&
V-Y = t\frac{Y}{B^2} \\
X(t) = \frac{A^2U}{t+A^2}&,&
Y(t) = \frac{B^2 V}{t+B^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
The closest point $(X,Y)$ should also belong to the first quadrant which imposes $t>-B^2$.
Finally one must find the unique root in the interval $[-B^2,+\infty]$ of the rationale function
$$
F(t)=
\frac{X(t)^2}{A^2}+\frac{Y(t)^2}{B^2}-1=
\left[ \frac{AU}{t+A^2} \right]^2+
\left[ \frac{BV}{t+B^2} \right]^2-1
$$
Once $t$ is found, the distance from the point $(U,V)$ to the ellipse is
$$
d=
t
\sqrt{\frac{X(t)^2}{A^4}+\frac{Y(t)^2}{B^4}}=
t
\sqrt{
\frac{U^2}{(t+A^2)^2}+
\frac{V^2}{(t+B^2)^2}
}
$$
The whole approach has been described in Eberly 1.

So if I understood it correctly for a general ellipse which is rotated by $\theta$ and has center $C_\circ$ we first rotate a given point $[p_x,p_y]$ by $-\theta$ around $C_\circ$ and subtract $C_\circ$ to get $[u,v]$. If $u,v$ is below zero we mirror it at the axis and finally get $[U,V]$. Good idea, this makes the problem less compute intensive.
